# Run multiple local terminal processes with Fabric

Tags: python, django, parallel-processing, fabric

new to using fabric. I have a project with a django backend and angular front end. I'm trying to make running the project locally easier with a fabfile. Here is the part of the script where I'm stuck...

```
# activate venv and start backend server
with lcd(projectpath), prefix('. venv/bin/activate'):
    local(projectpath+backendfolder+'manage.py runserver')

# start frontend server <==== FAB STOPS HERE!!
with lcd(projectpath+frontendfolder):
    local('npm start')
```

I have managed to get my virtual environment started and manage.py runserver to work. However fabric stops there and doesnt continue executing starting my angular server. This is obviously because this is a serial process.

How can I get the angular server running as a new terminal process after my django server is running?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue: when you run your backend server, it opens a shell which will hang (like a local shell) and, this time, block all the others. Using the `nohup` linux tool, as well as `pty=False` as a 2nd argument worked for me:

```
run('nohup {} &> /dev/null &'.format(your_command), pty=False)
```

I had to set `pty=False`, but you may not be obliged to do so. Try without it first.

And also, if `nohup` doesn't work, [this link from Fabric's FAQ](http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang) proposes alternative solutions, which might help you.